# ProgressBar In Windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Anyone can Give code samples for how to use progressbar in windows phone 7.

Comment: Can you give us more detail? What are you looking for in particular? It's fairly standard to set min and max values, then bind to the value.

The WP7 progress bar also has "IsIndeterminate" to show a general activity indicator, instead of progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use the ProgressBar class to add a progress bar to your
>   application. However, if you plan on adding an indeterminate progress
>   bar, using ProgressBar can decrease the performance of your
>   application. This is because the current implementation of ProgressBar
>   runs an indeterminate progress bar on the UI thread, rather than the
>   compositor thread.
>
> Instead, you can use the CustomIndeterminateProgressBar sample to add
>   an indeterminate progress bar that runs on the compositor thread for
>   better performance. This topic describes how the sample works, and how
>   you can use it to add an indeterminate progress bar to your
>   application.

[How to: Create a Custom Indeterminate Progress Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442303%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: You should instead use the new [ProgressIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.progressindicator(v=VS.92).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Jeff Wilcox, a developer at Microsoft has released a progress bar that might be useful: [A high performance ProgressBar for Windows Phone](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/)

Answer (score 6):

In XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Height="40" Name="progressBar1" Width="300" />
```

In code-behind:

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
progressBar1.Value = 39;
```