# How to show progress bar while loading a page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a page in my windows phone 8 app, which takes 1-3 seconds to load.

I use this statement to load the page

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/sleep_main.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

I want to display a progressbar of any type while my page loads.

Plz help how to to do this.

Comment: This has been covered [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265035/progressbar-in-windows-phone-7) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353113/windows-phone-8-performance-progressbar) before, you should really search before asking a question!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your page:

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="true" />
```

You can set parameters for this control.
Let see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.progressbar(v=vs.105).aspx